# Is there a way to force all subclasses to be sealed?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have an project requirement, which an specific abstract class should force all subclasses to be sealed C#, for instance:

```
public abstract class BaseProcess {
}

public sealed class HealthCheck : BaseProcess {
//Valid class
}

public class EtlSales : BaseProcess {
//Invalid, should emit a warning or a error when i compile
}
```

There's a data annotation or keyword, that force this configuration?

Comment: No. Why do you need that? Seems like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: While I second HimBromBeere, I think it would be possible to create an analyzer ... [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) _"The .NET Compiler Platform SDK provides the tools you need to create custom warnings that target C# or Visual Basic code. Your analyzer contains code that recognizes violations of your rule. Your code fix contains the code that fixes the violation."_ Sounds like what you want.

Comment: What actual **problem** are you trying to solve here? I can´t imagine why one should need that.

Comment: So, you somehow know up-front that *no possible two classes derived from `BaseProcess` now, or in the future, might have some common functionality that could belong in an intermediate class*? That seems incredibly unlikely.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i'm developing a reflection based process manager, for a windows service app, but i don't want that other developers reuse an existing process

Comment: But `sealed` won´t help you to *not use something*, just to *not subclass something*, or am I missing anything? Any other dev can still **use** that process in his own class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere He wrote "**re**use". I guess he actually means "subclass".

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, C# does not have such an option.

Comment: C# does not, but the .NET Compiler Platform SDK somewhat does (Analyzers). The question is if it is reasonable to enforce the required rule. But assuming it _is_ reasonable, then you could do it.